# How can I add an RSS widget using WP-CLI?

Tags: wp-cli

I can add an rss widget with this command:

```
wp widget add rss my-sidebar --title=News --items=5
```

But when I add a URL parameter, like this:

```
wp widget add rss my-sidebar --title=News --items=5 --url='https://news.example.com/feed/'
```

Or like this:

```
wp widget add rss my-sidebar --title=News --items=5 --url=https://news.example.com/feed/
```

Or like this:

```
wp widget add rss my-sidebar --title=News --items=5 --url="https://news.example.com/feed/"
```

Or any other configuration, it complains `Error: Invalid sidebar.`. When I add the sidebar and then try to update the URL parameter, with:

```
wp widget update rss-6 --url='https://news.example.com/feed/'
```

Or even:

```
wp widget update rss-6 --url=https:\/\/news\.example\.com\/feed\/
```

It says `Error: Specified widget isn't present on sidebar.` How can I get it to properly add an RSS widget? I feel like there's something I'm not properly escaping.

Comment: This is a clash with the global `--url` parameter and not availabe to sub-commands, as mentioned in this [open ticket](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/1222)